# How to make cookie setting permanent

Tags: support, stackexchange

Every time I log in I’m asked to confirm or choose cookie settings. How can I make the site remember my choices so I don’t have to choose every time I log in?  Sorry if this is not the right site to ask the question. I did a search and got no hits and got a tip from another user this is where to go for help. It happens on my MacBook Pro with safari. I have cookies allowed - or at least none are blocked. I do not see where to specifically use individual settings. I get the same pop up on my iPhone 13 pro with safari and on Firefox browsers on both devices and on iPad. Still trying to figure out the Firefox setting though. While I have not blocked any on Firefox I can’t even find their setting on the desktop or phone…. Here is the pop up I get when I logon each time. I choose my settings and save them. Have to do it each time. I do not get any error messages.

[image: pop up]

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed at length in the main meta site.

[The cookie consent dialog (coming from cookielaw.org) keeps popping up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362091/222623)

You should now get an error if your browser settings are preventing the changes from being saved. Saving your changes requires your browser to accept cookies, even if your preference is to not allow cookies — something needs to save that preference!

Any more specific guidance needs more detail in your question regarding device/OS and browser versions.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that link! Ii didint know the site was ignoring privacy Settings.